# How to only show specific values using Angular 8 keyvalue pipe

Tags: javascript, angular

I am wondering how I can only show specific values with the key-value pipe. So far I have tried to do `item.value.form_name` but that comes up as `null` when the property is set from my API. When I do `item.value` then it shows me all of the items in the object. I only want the form name and the organization to show.

Code:

```html
  <div class="form-details">
    <div *ngFor="let item of form?.results | keyvalue">
      <span class="col-6">{{item.value.id}}</span>
      <span class="col-6">{{item.value.org}}</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

How the data is being received
[image]

Comment: Its a built-in pipe that comes with angular https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dftdsf?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of form?.results | keyvalue">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.key == 'id' || item.key == 'org'">
        <span class="col-6">{{item.value}}</span>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
 <div class="form-details">
<div *ngFor="let item of form?.results | keyvalue">
  <span class="col-6">{{item.value.id == 'null' ? '' : item.value.id}}</span>
  <span class="col-6">{{item.value.org == 'null'? '' : item.value.org}}</span> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-details">
    <div *ngFor="let item of results | keyvalue">
        <div *ngIf="item.key == 'id' || item.key == 'org'">
            <span class="col-6">{{item.value}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't repeat the same answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can minimize the code with some thing like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of form?.results | keyvalue">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.key == ('id' || 'org')">
        <span class="col-6">{{item.value}}</span>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```